# Grails form after save prevent data from history back button

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to prevent input fields being showed again after Form submission gorm saving from Controller and hitting the browser's back history button. Something like clearing the fields after gorm saves it?

Answer (score 1):

Most browser cache form input values. When you hit back it renders old data. You can use `autocomplete="off"` to prevent the browser from refilling the old data.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make a `Filter` that adds header to ask the browser to always download the content from backend on each request. This can have negative performance effect but if you don't need to care about it:

```
class CachePreventionFilters {

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            after = {
                response.setHeader('Cache-Control', "no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is catch for both cache-control and auto-complete. Both of the solution shall work but try out which one works for you.

Solution #1 - Try adding autocomplete="off" with gsp/html form element.

Solution #2- Set below parameter to your http response

```
        response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store')
        response.setHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache')
```

Hope this helps !!